# How can I create an accordion using knockout JS?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-accordion

Adding the following custom binding handler seems to break the accordion, is this due to the version of knockout?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor() || {};
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).accordion(options);
    }, 0);

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function(){
          $(element).accordion("destroy");
      });
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor() || {};
    $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion(options);
}
```

}

Comment: What's broken about it? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update to knockout 2.2, the accordion custom binding handler needs to have a reference to the updateOn, so excessive bindings are not called for every event on the accordion.

```
   <ul data-bind="foreach: items, accordion:{updateOn: items}"></ul>

   ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).accordion(options);
        }, 0);

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
          ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function(){
              $(element).accordion("destroy");
          });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        if (options.updateOn && ko.isObservable(options.updateOn)) {
            options.updateOn();
        }
        $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion(options);
    }
}
```